# The Collazt conjecture in Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a function that takes a number and runs it through the conjecture. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. I'm a beginner so I don't know why it doesn't work. Instead of running through the numbers and stopping at 1, it just goes on forever. If someone could take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong whit it, that would be really helpful.

```
def collatz(number):
    number = int(number)
```

`while number != 1:
    if number == 1:
        break()

    if number%2 == 0:
        number = number//2
        print(str(number))

    if number%2 == 1:
        number = 3*number+1
        print(str(number))

collatz(5)`

Comment: first thing, this `if number == 1:
        break()` is useless because it is redundant with your while condition

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `break()` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number that will stop at 1 must pass by the value 2 first.

But, since your test for evenity and oddity are right after one another, if `number == 2` at the begining of your loop, then:

- It is even, so it gets divided by 2.
- Then 1 is immediatly tested for oddity, which it is, so it is multiplied by 3.

Then the loop continues with `number == 3`.

To fix it, replace your second `if` by `elif` to only test one option each time.

Comment: I'd replace second `if` by `else`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already mentioned your if/else problem. Here's a shorter version of your code:

```
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        print(number)
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1

    print(number)

collatz(5)
```

And its output:

```
$ python test.py
5
16
8
4
2
1
```